# Is this function concave or convex?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

let $g_{n,\gamma}(\sigma)$ be the function defined as the following 
$$
g_{n,\gamma}(\sigma)= \left(\frac{(\sigma-1)^2 +\gamma^2}{\sigma^2
+\gamma^2} \right)^{n/2} T_n\left( \frac{\sigma(\sigma-1)
+\gamma^2}{\sigma^2 +\gamma^2}\right).
$$
Where $T_n$ is the Tchebychev polynomial of  first kind and degree $n,$  $\sigma \in ]0,1[$ and $\gamma >0.$ Is this function concave or convex
i.e have we  $g_{n,\gamma}(\sigma) + g_{n,\gamma}(1-\sigma)\leq 2
g_{n,\gamma}(1/2)$?
Many thanks,
Khadija

Comment: It is easy to see by plotting that $g_{n,\gamma}$ is neither concave nor convex for most values of $n$ and $\gamma$.  The main point is that the graph of $T_n$ is too wiggly.  Anyway, this question would be better at math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maple says $g_{5,1}(\sigma)$ is neither convex nor concave for $\sigma \in ]0,1]$:

> restart; with(orthopoly):
>   Student[Calculus1]:-FunctionPlot((((sigma-1)^2+1)/(sigma^2+1))^(5/2)*U(5,
>   ( sigma * (sigma-1)+1)/(sigma^2+1)), sigma = 0 .. 1);

[image]

See [orthopoly](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=orthopoly) and [FunctionPlot](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Student/Calculus1/FunctionChart) for info.

Addition. The same with the ones of the first kind:

> restart; with(orthopoly):
>   Student[Calculus1]:-FunctionPlot((((sigma-1)^2+1)/(sigma^2+1))^(5/2)*T(5,
>   (sigma *(sigma-1)+1)/(sigma^2+1)), sigma = 0 .. 1);
>   [image]

Comment: Thanks alot @user64494. Is it the same thing if $T_n$ is the Chebychev polynomial of first kind?

Comment: @ Khadija Mbarki : Yes, it is. See addition to my answer.

Comment: Could you check @user64494 if this identity holds true $$g_{n,\gamma}(\sigma) + g_{n,\gamma}(1-\sigma)= 2 g_{n,\gamma}(1/2)$$ holds true if and only if $\sigma=1/2$?